# How to save the output of a windows batch script in xlsx format?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have  a Windows batch script where I get the output from a function in a tab delimited columns into an xls file as seen below:

```
call :MyFunction > File.xls
```

I want the file to be saved in xlsx format is there any way I can do it.
I am not sure if PowerShell (or VB) is capable of doing this like:

```
call :MyFunction | powershell  -Command " & {output > xlsx}"
```

Comment: you can use csv, Excel can parse it (Export-Csv). have a look at [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/d41565f1-37ef-43cb-9462-a08cd5a610e2) as well or [this](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

Comment: Yes, open it in Microsoft Excel choose 'Save As', select a location to save to, then make sure the 'Save as type:' drop down box reads 'Excel Document (*.xlsx)'!

Comment: Actualy i have to give the xlsx file as an input to another program... i can't do it manually "save as'

Comment: xlsx is a binary format that consists of a number of XML files in a zip archive. While it's technically possible to create this from batch, it'd be a pain in the rear to actually do. Create the file as CSV and load that into Excel. If you have Excel available, you can control it via its COM interface from VBScript or PowerShell.

Comment: You probably aren't outputting it to an Excel file, you are outputting a tab delimited text file. There is no built in function to convert a text file, which usually has a `.csv` extension into the Excel XML file format. My advice is to use the `.csv` file extension and send that to the client for them to open in Excel, or do it yourself using a third party utility or the COM interface as suggested above.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+Powershell+write.

Answer (score 1):

you can use csv, Excel can parse it (Export-Csv). have a look at [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/d41565f1-37ef-43cb-9462-a08cd5a610e2) as well or [this](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)

I figured I might as well use that as an answer